# What is the name of such collection / algorithm that looksup elements via "buckets"

Tags: java

This collection works logically as map but allows to lookup elements by its prefix. It consists of nested `Maps` in which every nested map corresponds to elements that matches next token of the key.

For example:

Lets have `bar` as a map key.
Lets tokenize that `bar` int "subkeys": `b`,`a`,`r`. Then we would put `value` using following method (pseudocode)

1. From root map `Map<String,Value or Map>` get `b`or put new `Map<String,Value or Map` if absent
2. From map from previous step get `a`or put new `Map<String,Value or Map>` if absent
3. In map from previous step, set or replace value under key `r`

Retrieval is similar (pseudocode)

1. Take `b` bucket from root map
2. Take `a` bucket from previous bucket
3. Take `r` take value under `r` from previous bucket

How is such collection called? I would call it a GraphMap or BucketGraph. But what is the proper name?

Comment: A [Prefix Tree, or Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe sounds very much like a [Trie, or Prefix Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). It can be used to sort strings or other objects into buckets based on the individual characters of a word, or words in a sentence, or other types of "sequentian decomposition" (not sure if *that* is the right term...).

Answer (score 2):

You are very likely searching for a [Trie](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.4/org/apache/commons/collections4/Trie.html), also called a [Prefix or Digital Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). The first link will redirect you to the Apache Commons library, which implements this kind of tree.

Comment: It is okay, as long as you have your answer and you chose one :).